# Page Waits Until Query Runs Before Displaying. Recently Added 1&1 SSL Cert

Tags: php, html, mysql, ssl, ssl-certificate

I recently played with installing a 'GeoTrust QuickSSL Premium' from my host 1&1 since it came free with my hosting package.

I've noticed a distinct change after installing the SSL cert.  I have a page (php) which runs a query (from a MySQL db) and displays the query results.  The query takes 15-30 seconds to run.  Prior to getting the SSL cert, the page would display and load all the 'html elements' and then display the query results once it was done.  Now after the SSL cert, the page won't display until it the query is finished loading.

I do not like this as I have a message on the page that informs the user of the potential delay in loading the page.

I tried to unassign the SSL cert and assign to another domain, but it says that can only be done once every 30 days?  Any ideas?  And what is the cause of this behavior?

Thanks!!

Comment: What's your query? You might be able to improve it's runtime. And anyway you can use ajax for loading the query separately.

Comment: Never had this issue before messing with SSL cert.  I think resolving that issue directly first would make the most sense.